# Unable to Send Custom headers for zap-api-scan.py, headers are declared in options.prop

Tags: owasp, zap, zap-api-scan

Unable to send Custom headers for zap-api-scan.py, headers are declared in options.prop

I want to use zap to scan a rest API endpoint which requires Authorization & X-api-key header.

To specify the header, I have configured these in options.prop file.

But when I run
docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t **<API URL>** -f openapi -z "-configfile /zap/wrk/options.prop"

I feel prop file is not getting picked. I get 401 error, as my Authorization token is not picked up.

Below is how my options.prop file looks

```
replacer.full_list(0).description=Authorization
 replacer.full_list(0).enabled=true replacer.full_list(0).matchtype=REQ_HEADER  
 replacer.full_list(0).matchstr=Authorization 
 replacer.full_list(0).regex=false 
 replacer.full_list(0).replacement=<Token>
 replacer.full_list(1).description=x-api-key
 replacer.full_list(1).enabled=true
 replacer.full_list(1).matchtype=REQ_HEADER
 replacer.full_list(1).matchstr=x-api-key
 replacer.full_list(1).regex=false
 replacer.full_list(1).replacement=<Value>
```

Comment: Already asked on the ZAP User Group: https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users/c/Db07FvKUdCU/m/OOykkPr2AwAJ
The people who really know about ZAP will answer on the user group first ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make your command like this:

```
zap-api-scan.py -I -t /zap/wrk/sp_openapi_main.json -f openapi -d -n /zap/wrk/default.context -z "-configfile /zap/wrk/options.prop" -r `pwd`/ZAP_REPORT.html -w `pwd`/ZAP_REPORT.md
```

You can use this format for adding "option.prop":

```
replacer.full_list(0).description=Authorization_Basic
replacer.full_list(0).enabled=true
replacer.full_list(0).matchtype=REQ_HEADER
replacer.full_list(0).matchstr=Authorization
replacer.full_list(0).regex=false
replacer.full_list(0).replacement=<your_value>
```

For more details:
https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users/c/Db07FvKUdCU/m/OOykkPr2AwAJ
https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/how-do-you-find-out-what-key-to-use-to-set-a-config-value-on-the-command-line/
https://www.zaproxy.org/blog/2017-06-19-scanning-apis-with-zap/#authentication